# trying to install xdebug: configure file not found

Tags: php, linux, xdebug

I am following these instructions to download xdebug: http://xdebug.org/wizard.php. The output of the wizard was this:

```
Summary

Xdebug installed: no
Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
Windows: no
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 5.4.17
Zend API nr: 220100525
PHP API nr: 20100525
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: no
Configuration File Path: /bitnami/mampstack-osx-x64/output/php/lib
Configuration File: /Applications/mampstack-5.4.17-2/php/etc/php.ini
Extensions directory: /Applications/mampstack-5.4.17-2/php/lib/php/extensions
```

giving these instructions

1. Download xdebug-2.2.3.tgz
2. Unpack the downloaded file with tar -xvzf xdebug-2.2.3.tgz
3. Run: cd xdebug-2.2.3 Run: phpize (See the FAQ if you don't have phpize.
4. Run: ./configure

Everything works properly up to step #4. In step #4 I get

```
MyMacBookAir$ ./configure
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

If I look in xdebug-2.2.3 I see that there is no file called configure -- but I do see a file called configure.in. Did I get .tgz that is missing the configure file? Or am I not understanding some part of the instructions properly?

Answer (score 9):

Actually it could be a problem with **phpize** command
If it complains for autoconf ("Cannot find autoconf") then try next

```
curl -OL http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/autoconf/autoconf-latest.tar.gz
tar xzf autoconf-latest.tar.gz
cd autoconf-*
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: This was the issue in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

@akh2103 I assume you have your problem fixed by now but I leave this answer here for anybody else has this issue.

I've just suffered from the same problem. For me I was installing it on a linked directory

eg ~/Downloads was actually on /media/1234/Data/Downloads

For some reason when I transferred all my downloads onto my other HDD the other day the permissions have been haywire.

After I moved the initial xdebug file to my `~/.Desktop` and unpacked it there I ran

```
chmod -R 0755 x-debug/
```

and then ran `phpize`

Then I could see the configure file that didn't appear when I tried to do it on my other HDD.

I hope this helps anybody else who suffered from this problem.

John